# Conditional to detect a drive

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, streamwriter

I am having a lot of trouble trying to make a conditional to detect whether a drive (flash drive e: ) is connected to the computer. If it is not, I just want to send it to the c drive.

Here is my code:

```
        StreamWriter sw;
        sw = File.AppendText ("E:\\SignIn.txt");
        sw.WriteLine ("Date and Time: " + label5.Text + " | Name: " + Name_Box.Text + " | Company: " + Company_Box.Text + " | Visiting: " + Visiting_Box.Text + " |");
        sw.Close ();
```

I need that to be sent to the flash drive (E:) and then if the flash drive is not connected I would need t shoot it over to the c: drive.

Thank you.

Comment: search here in SO how to detect when flash drive is connected or not first ;-) was answered right some days ago.

Comment: What if the flash drive is not E?  When I put in a flash drive at work, it comes in as drive G:, but at home it comes in as drive I:.  If you hard code E: in your code, it will very likely not work on another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple if/else and choose where you would like it to go

```
if (Directory.Exists(@"E:\")){

StreamWriter sw;         
sw = File.AppendText ("E:\\SignIn.txt");         
sw.WriteLine ("Date and Time: " + label5.Text + " | Name: " + Name_Box.Text + "Company: " + Company_Box.Text + " | Visiting: " + Visiting_Box.Text + " |");         
sw.Close ();
}

else{
StreamWriter sw;         
sw = File.AppendText ("C:\\SignIn.txt");         
sw.WriteLine ("Date and Time: " + label5.Text + " | Name: " + Name_Box.Text + "Company: " + Company_Box.Text + " | Visiting: " + Visiting_Box.Text + " |");         
sw.Close ();    
}
```

Comment: This was PERFECT! For what ever reason when I first tried this I had the same code beneath antecedent, and got an error with StreamWriter in the consequent. But I believe it was due to the "if (Directory.Exists(@"E:\"))" I had "if (Directory.Exists(E:)) and was getting that error. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Check `if (Directory.Exists(@"E:\"))`.

Comment: That was probably my problem I was using

        if (Directory.Exists(E:\))